# Retrieve Data From IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

[CrossPost From MSDN]

I had a task that, I need to send a generic List to a method, where I need to iterate it and convert it to an Excel File. I already did this with Data Table, but with Generic  list I am facing some problems (I don't want to convert my generic list to Data Table). I will paste the code which helps me out for an answer.

I Had Two Generic Lists

```
            List<User>       objList = new List<User>();
            List<Student> objStudent = new List<Student>();
```

// I am adding some Item to List

```
            User obj = new User(1, "aaa");
            User obj1 = new User(2, "bbb");
            User obj2 = new User(3, "ccc");
            User obj3 = new User(4, "ddd");


            Student sobj = new Student(1, "aaa");
            Student sobj1 = new Student(2, "bbb");
            Student sobj2 = new Student(3, "ccc");
            Student sobj3 = new Student(4, "ddd");
            objList.Add(obj);ExportToExcel(objList);
```

To Export it to Excel , I am passing the lists to the below methods as

```
    public void ExportToExcel<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        PropertyInfo[] piT = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        var Users = list.ToList();

        Type myType = (typeof(T));
    }
```

When I am passing my list to Ienumerable... I am not able to retrieve the data present in the List IEnumerable list. If I retrieve the data , then I can handle further. Could any one suggest me the better Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to access the values of all the properties on type `T`, you can use the [`PropertyInfo.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx) method:

```
public void ExportToExcel<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        foreach(var property in properties)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(item, null);

            // Do something else with the property's value
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit in response to comment**

You indicated you might receive a single list or a list of lists. You can add another overload which takes the composed lists, then iterate through it and export each individual list:

```
public void ExportToExcel<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> itemSets)
{
    foreach(var itemSet in itemSets)
    {
        ExportToExcel(itemSet);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Bryan Thank you for an answer. But a small doubt that, if i get my value in {{var value = property.GetValue(item, null)}} as a Generic list, how do i iterate it? I failed to this? could you please help me out in this?

Comment: @Bhuvan: `value` will be typed as `object`, so if you need a more specific type, you will have to cast it. It is tough to give you guidance without a more specific example; can you provide more information as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: :- From the BL, i may receive any type of List to my method, so i may receive a single list(You had provided a sample snippet for this). or a parent list containing ALL Child Lists. But the problem comes with List With in a List and i am not able to cast and iterate  the terms in child List. As value Type is OBJECT, so in DAL i may not know the Entity Type because i am receiving my List as IEnumerable<T>. So i need an information that how do we iterate the Child Lists, if we any choice

Comment: @Bhuvan: It sounds like you want to walk through child lists if a property happens to be a list. I updated the answer to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

If your always going to work with `List<T>` you could change `IEnumerable<T>` to `IList<T>`. AFAIK the IEnumerable interface does not define methods for accessing the data inside the collection, only to iterate it.

You could even use `ICollection<T>` if it suits your needs.

Comment: `IList` may not, but `IList<T>` certainly does. Besides, unless the OP needs to _add_ data to their collection `IEnumerable<T>` should be more than sufficient and as long as the backend data source is coded to handle it, it supports lazy loading of data. This can make a world of difference in performance. The OP seems a bit vague though so I can't tell if they're trying to read an object from the collection or a property of an object _in_ the collection.

Comment: I ignored the <T> thinking it wouldn't cause any confusion so I just put it. As to the performance part even I would like a further explanation :)

Comment: Feel free to ask a question (though it'll likely be closed as a dupe ;)).

Comment: Where can I find Microsoft documentation on where each interface mentioned above uses lazy or eager loading?

Comment: The interfaces themselves don't, but the fact that they are interfaces leaves the implementation up to the underlying datasource (that is where the real magic happens). A good starting point would be to lookup `yield return` in C#.

Comment: Thank you for both. I enjoyed your explanation. @M.Babcock as you said "it makes world of difference in performance" , will you please elborate because i want to know, whether it effects the perfomance of an application or not

Comment: @Bhuvan he explains that IEnumerable uses `Lazy Loading` of Data http://bit.ly/wllUbn which doesn't initialize any value until the are requested, which makes a difference in performance if your loading a really huge list, contrary to eager loading that may be faster if items are fewer because validations (and calls to underlying datasource if any) are minimized. What we're now discussing is how do we know how does .NET implements those interfaces.

Comment: @Bhuvan - In reality it depends on your usage. If you're going to iterate the entire collection each time anyway then it only postpones the inevitable, but if you're using LINQ (for example) it can make the difference of only qualifying a portion of the data as potentially compared to all of it (think `SingleOrDefault` which is intended to only ever consider a single result in a data set of potentially hundreds if not millions of objects). It really changes the way one thinks about their DAL and can affect an application's architecture fundamentally.

Comment: @PedroC88 - Sorry I only chat when someone is so hard headed that they are missing the fundamentals and it appears (based on your last comment) that you seem to understand the basic concept at least which is enough for you to do your own research. There are plenty of resources available online to help you with your question (and will do a better job explaining than I ever could). It really is a fundamental concept that I think every .NET (3.5+) developer should understand thoroughly so I wish you the best of luck in your journey on the flagship Google.